# SINGLE SELECT Query for MAX Count with JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, max

I have three tables: Customers, Vehicles, and Sales. I need a single SELECT Statement that will form an output containing three columns: VEHICLEMAKE, SALESBYMAKE, and CUSTOMERFULLNAME. The output should look similar to the following:

```
VEHICLEMAKE SALES_BY_MAKE CUSTOMERFULLNAME

Chevrolet              11 Adam E Whitney           
                          Alberto L Ross           
                          Alexis T Moon            
                          Finley H Tritt           
                          Jayda V Rush             
                          Junior E Hanes           
                          Kamari H Webster         
                          Linda L Lawrence         
                          Luke E Boyer             
                          Samantha D Holden        
                          Sydnee B Herman
```

The list should only contain the MAX number of SALESBYMAKE, unless the MAX is tied, then it would also contain the VEHICLEMAKE, number of SALESBYMAKE, and CUSTOMERFULLNAME for the other VEHICLEMAKE. I've been working this for hours, to absolutely no avail! Here are the tables, only containing the necessary attributes.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(customerID     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
customerFirName     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerLasName     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerMiName      VARCHAR(1)  NOT NULL;

CREATE TABLE VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN     VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
vehicleMake     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL;

CREATE TABLE SALES
(saleID         INT     PRIMARY KEY,
customerID      INT,
vehicleVIN      VARCHAR(25);
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(customerID),
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (vehicleVIN) REFERENCES VEHICLES(vehicleVIN);
```

EDIT: Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.VEHICLEMAKE, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VEHICLEVIN) "SALES_BY_MAKE", c.CUSTOMERFULLNAME, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CUSTOMERZIP)"CUSTOMERS"
FROM SALES s, VEHICLES v, CUSTOMERS c
WHERE s. VEHICLEVIN = v. VEHICLEVIN
and c. CUSTOMERID = s. CUSTOMERID
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

The issue is, this gives me the entire list, instead of the MAX values. I don't know exactly where or how to implement the MAX statement to only include the VEHICLE MAKE that was purchased the most.

I have also tried this, as recommended by another person whom I asked, but couldn't make any sense of it and it did not execute without error.

```
SELECT vc.*
FROM (SELECT vc.*, MAX(SALES_BY_MAKE) OVER () as MAX_SALES_BY_MAKE
  FROM (SELECT v.VEHICLEMAKE, c.CUSTOMERFULLNAME,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VEHICLEVIN) as SALES_BY_MAKE
        FROM SALES s JOIN
             VEHICLES v
             ON s.VEHICLEVIN = v VEHICLEVIN JOIN
             CUSTOMERS c
             ON c.CUSTOMERID = s.CUSTOMERID 
       ) vc
 ) vc
WHERE SALES_BY_MAKE = MAX_SALES_BY_MAKE
ORDER BY VEHICLEMAKE;
```

I'm thinking the first one I tried is the right path to head down, since it does indeed provide the list that I need, however it is not selecting only the MAX values, rather it is providing all of the values and ordering them from highest to lowest. I considered adding a LIMIT, but that wouldn't allow for a "tie."

I really just need guidance on where/how to implement a MAXcount to obtain just the highest output.

Comment: This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. (And no, *I'd upload it but...* does not count as effort, any more than *Honest, I did my homework, but my dog ate it*). Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: yup! you can do it.

Comment: `I'd upload what I've tried` eager to see that, it won't confuse us at all.

Comment: My apologies. I truly thought it would add confusion. Won't make that mistake again. Not trying to get "free" work out of you. Edited post to include what I've tried and the specific issue that I need some assistance with. Thanks again.

Comment: Have a look at `GROUP BY`

Comment: I'm not an expert, but i don't think that you could display a table without repeating the values for vehicle make and sales by make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up doing the trick!

```
WITH
vehicleMakeCount AS
(
    SELECT
        SALES.saleID, SALES.customerID, SALES.vehicleVIN, VEHICLES.vehicleMake,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY VEHICLES.vehicleMake) AS salesByMake
    FROM
        SALES
        INNER JOIN
            VEHICLES ON VEHICLES.vehicleVIN  = SALES.vehicleVIN
),
salesRank AS
(
    SELECT
        vehicleMakeCount.*,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salesByMake DESC)   AS vehicleMakeSalesRank
    FROM
        vehicleMakeCount
)
SELECT CUSTOMERS.customerFullName, salesRank.vehicleMake
FROM
salesRank
    INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMERS
    ON CUSTOMERS.customerID = salesRank.customerID
    WHERE
    salesRank.vehicleMakeSalesRank = 1
    ORDER BY salesRank.vehicleMake;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, its just that it will repeat the values on first 2 columns

```
SELECT  C.vehicleMake,C.nCount,B.customerFirName + ' ' + B.customerMiName     + ' ' + B.customerLasName cFullName
FROM SALES A
JOIN CUSTOMERS B ON A.customerID = B.customerID
JOIN    (
    SELECT A.vehicleVIN,B.vehicleMake,COUNT(*) nCount
    FROM SALES
    JOIN VEHICLES B ON A.vehicleVIN = B.vehicleVIN
    GROUP BY A.vehicleVIN,B.vehicleMake
    )C ON A.vehicleVIN = C.vehicleVIN
```

Comment: Just tried this...Unfortunately it's not working. Here's the error:
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00904: "A"."VEHICLEVIN": invalid identifier

Can't figure out why either. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, i missed the alias for the sales table. Try putting an alias 'A' on sales table on the last part on the query. I don't know if this will work on oracle but in sql server its a working query.

Comment: Got it. I'll give that a try! Seems simple enough and the logic makes sense to me. I'll run it this evening and update you if it works in Oracle. I don't see why it wouldn't. Syntax seems the same.

Comment: I just ran it and although it executes w/o error, it still isn't right. this is basically producing a list of sales, pairing the vehicles sold with their buyer. Instead of the output only listing one make (like Chevrolet For Example), it lists all of the makes. Instead of it only listing one sales count for the number of Chevrolet's sold, the sales count is "1" for everything, and the list reflects all customers, not just those who purchased the top car. 

Any guidance on where we went wrong here?

Comment: This is a query for SQL Server, I don't know if its the same for Oracle.